# How do I reorder the columns in table

Tags: r

How can I reorder the columns of my table in R. Class is "table"

```
>dput(booking_com_graph)
 structure(c(75L, 99L, 3L, 0L, 51L, 121L, 101L, 94L, 12L, 0L, 
 46L, 170L, 92L, 143L, 2L, 0L, 43L, 213L, 90L, 80L, 32L, 26L, 
 27L, 157L, 90L, 126L, 14L, 0L, 50L, 165L), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("Brand", "Direct", "Marketing", "Referral", 
    "SEO", "Train"), c("August", "July", "June", "October", 
    "September")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `match` the `month.name` with the column names of the dataset and use that as index to reorder the columns

```
df1 <- booking_com_graph[,match(month.name, colnames(booking_com_graph), nomatch=0)]
```

Or we could have avoided this by converting the 'month' column in the original dataset to `factor` and specify the levels as `month.name` before we do the `table`.